# Синтаксис установки переменной окружения

Tags: bash, unix

Объясните синтаксис установки переменной окружения в линукс.

Например здесь:

`export PATH=~/folder:${PATH}`

Зачем нужна часть после двоеточия? Что она делает? Почему нельзя написать просто `export PATH=~/folder` ?

Отличается ли эта команда чем-то принципиальным от такого:

`export PATH=$PATH:~/folder` ?

Почему в первом варианте путь указан до двоеточия, а часть с PATH после двоеточия, а во втором варианте наоборот? Будут ли они работать по-разному? Почему в первом варианте ставятся фигурные скобки вокруг PATH, а во втором не ставятся? В чём разница?

Comment: Грубо говоря, используется просто конкатенация строк. Большая часть вопросов отпадет, если просматривать результат каждой операции `echo $VAR`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Переменная **PATH** указывает список каталогов и их порядок, в которых будет осуществляться поиск исполняемого файла оболочкой системы.

Например `echo $PATH`,

```
/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

**Зачем нужна часть после двоеточия?**

Если написать так `export PATH=~/folder`, то переменная PATH потеряет предыдущее значение и будет равна исключительно тому, что ей присвоено. В результате, например, `ls -l` будет доступен только по абсолютному пути `/bin/ls -l`.

Чтобы сохранить текущее значение PATH, его надо добавить после двоеточия:

```
export PATH=~/folder:$PATH
```

либо наоборот, до двоеточия:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/folder
```

В результате к переменной PATH будет добавлен каталог `~/folder` (в начале, либо в конце) с сохранением предыдущих путей.
Если `~/folder` идет в начале, то поиск будет начинаться с этого каталога, если же в конце, то, соответственно, в нем исполняемый файл будет икаться в последнюю очередь (при условии, что он не будет найден в любом из предыдущих каталогов).

Фигурные скобки в данном случае непринципиальны, т.е. приведут к одинаковому результату.
А так они нужны для расширенной подстановки переменных, разных вычислений и манипуляций со значениями. Все это подробно с примерами есть в Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё стало понятно )) А то в сети много рецептов, в которых просто написано, что нужно вбивать в терминал, но не написано, почему именно так.

Answer (score 3):

> Зачем нужна часть после двоеточия? Что она делает?

это просто присвоение значения переменной:

```
имя_переменной=значение
```

> Почему нельзя написать просто export PATH=~/folder ?

можно, конечно. но переменная в этом случае получит совсем другое значение.

> Отличается ли эта команда чем-то принципиальным от такого:
>   `export PATH=$PATH:~/folder` ?

принципиально — ничем. просто в переменную попадут **разные** значения.

> Почему в первом варианте путь указан до двоеточия, а часть с PATH после двоеточия, а во втором варианте наоборот? Будут ли они работать по-разному?

тут уже вопрос из совсем другой области, связанной не с синтаксисом, а с семантикой: ведь значение [специальной переменной окружения PATH](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03) оказывает непосредственное влияние на [процесс поиска команд](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01): если команда не опознана как функция, псевдоним или встроенная команда оболочки, то поиск её производится в каталогах, перечисленных через двоеточие в этой самой переменной. каталоги перебираются слева направо, пока в очередном каталоге не будет найден исполняемый файл, имя которого совпадает с командой, потому порядок упоминания каталогов — важен: ведь файлы с одним и тем же именем (но с разным содержимым) могут встретиться в разных каталогах.

> Почему в первом варианте ставятся фигурные скобки вокруг PATH, а во втором не ставятся? В чём разница?

способы указания значения переменной — `$имя` и `${имя}` — абсолютно равноценны. второй способ можно рассматривать как один (наиболее простой) из вариантов записи т.н. [*parameter expansion*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02): `${имя:-слово}`, `${имя%слово}` и т.п.

также второй способ удобно (а порой и необходимо) применять для исключения неоднозначности. например, запись `$имя_` будет трактоваться как значение переменной с именем `имя_`, а запись `${имя}_` будет трактоваться как значение переменной с именем `имя`, к которому (значению) справа добавлен символ `_`.